# Почему моя капча не отображается, когда я перевожу свой капча id в массив байтов?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlet, графика

Работая с сервлетами, столкнулся с проблемой! Я генерирую капчу в моем сервлете регистрации, а затем помещаю идентификатор captcha в сессию, после чего я хочу достать этот `id` из сессии в своем капча сервлете и отрисовать ее там. Но она не отрисовываеться и я не пойму почему.

**CaptchaServlet:**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    CaptchaTypeManager captchaTypeManager = new CaptchaTypeManager(req, resp, captchaService);

    captchaTypeManager.getType(getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_TYPE));
    renderingCaptcha(resp, req);

    LOG.debug(getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_TYPE));
    LOG.debug(req.getSession().getAttribute("captchaId"));
}

private void renderingCaptcha(HttpServletResponse resp,  HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
    int width = 535;
    int height = 90;
    String captcha = String.valueOf(req.getSession().getAttribute("captchaId"));
    
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D graphics2D = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    Font font = new Font("Impact", Font.ITALIC, 34);
    graphics2D.setFont(font);
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    Random random = new Random();

    int x = 0;
    int y;

    char[] code = captchaService.getCaptchaById(captcha).toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        x += 75 + (Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 20);
        y = 50 + (Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 20);

        graphics2D.drawChars(captchaService.getCaptchaById(captcha).toCharArray(), i, 1, x, y);
    }

    graphics2D.dispose();
    resp.setContentType("image/png");
    OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

**Registration Servlet:**

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CaptchaGenerator captchaGenerator = new CaptchaGenerator(captchaService); // class that generated my captcha
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        captchaGenerator.generateCaptcha(httpServletResponse, baos); // method that generate my captcha
        httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("captchaId", captchaService.getId()); // here i putting my captchaId into session
        httpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(ConstantApp.JSPPages.REGISTRATION_PAGE).forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
```

**MyCapthcaGenerator:**

```
public void generateCaptcha() throws IOException {
    long id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String captchaId = captchaService.setId(String.valueOf(id));
    captchaService.put(captchaId, String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(99999) + 10000));
}
```

**Пример вывода:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он не отображает капчу, а просто выводит `id`, ошибки в стеке не выдаются, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишете контент из байт в респонс, но не установили `Content-Type` заголовок. Это означает что браузер не знает как интерпретировать полученные занные из тэга `<img src=..>`.

Параметр `HttpServletResponse` лишний в генераторе капчи. Нужно перенести строку

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
```

сюда

```
captchaTypeManager.getType(getServletContext().getInitParameter(ConstantApp.ContextType.CONTEXT_TYPE));
resp.setContentType("image/png");
OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(gg), os); // here i trying to draw my captcha.
os.flush();
```

Comment: Да, но тогда картинка отображается не корректно, на ней просто белый маленький квадрат, а самих цифр нет.

Comment: Надо добавить `os.flush()` после записи  `ImageIO` в стрим.

Comment: В сервлете регистрации не нужно, а в сервлете капчи да. Тут два стрима и `baos.close()` тоже желательно.

Comment: Я добавил но ничего не изменилось) Обновил пост

Comment: Параметр HttpServletResponse так и не убрали.

Comment: Убрал, просто не обновил эту часть, так же я убрал os.close(); с класса генератора в качестве теста, это не помогло)

Comment: Вы уничтожаете garaphics перед тем как записали image в стрим.

Comment: Да я понял свою ошибку, добавил решение

Comment: Вы можете сами добавить ответ на свой вопрос. Для этого не обязательно исправлять код с ошибками, который вы опубликовали ранее.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)